# Using Domain Name is Ampps

Tags: windows-10

How could I grant an application such as Ampps privileges to be able to edit hosts file.
I am running Windows 10 64bit.
I tried everywhere i could think of, I find no settings allowing Aamps to write to host file.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your question refers to the file
`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`, then only administrators
can modify it.

The program needs to be Run as Administrator to update this file.
But note that it will then have unrestricted access to your entire
system.
Unless you have absolute confidence in this program and are sure that
it can do no harm, I advise not to do that.

If you decide to do it anyway, take first backups of your data and
create a System Restore backup and also keep a copy of the `hosts`
file.